# FB.getLoginStatus - No response

Tags: javascript, facebook-sdk-3.0

FB.getLoginStatus( ... ) is having no effect in my code.  I have another app that's already published and working that I've matched settings with.  I've created test apps and used their id's without getLoginStatus to work.  FB.login(...) works though and if I didn't need to determine the user's status, I'd move on for now, but this is the last step in auth for me.

Here's an example of the app setup (w/ fakey domain masked by my hosts file):

[image: screenshot]

and the code using the sdk:

```
< div id="fb-root" > </ div >

...
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
    appId  : '<app_id>',
    logging : true,
    status : true,
    cookie : true,
    xfbml  : true,
});

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
    alert('logged in');
});

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
    alert('logged out');
});     
};

function getFBLoginStatus() {
FB.getLoginStatus( function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        alert(accessToken);
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        //login function
        alert('login first');
    } else {
        //login function
        alert('login first');
    }
}, true);
}

(function(d) {
var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all/debug.js";
ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
} (document));
...
< a href="#" onclick="getFBLoginStatus()" >test< /a >
```

As you can see, I've tried using the debug version & enabling logging on the sdk.
I've tried without ports, with ports, with hosts file, with publicly resolvable domains (.com & .sh).  I've tried multiple test apps.  I've cloned the js test console from www.fbrell.com.

I get no errors or warnings.  No logging from the sdk at all.  I've tried adding a breakpoint and stepping through and it ends in guard() function talking about an error that 'getLoginStatus' will be deprecated, but I think that's simply the debugger following the wrong path.

When I manually call FB.getLoginStatus(), I see the http requests and responses for https://www.facebook.com/connect/ping? return a successful 302 OK like I see on http://www.fbrell.com.  I've compared queryString params and they match.

I have NOT tried putting my site under ssl, but that shouldn't be necessary for development or with the app settings I've chosen.

I'll mention that my sites have been running as node servers (http and express), but I haven't used any custom headers.  I've tried running directly under nginx (w/ default conf) and had the same results. I've tried latest FF, Chrome, Safari (I'm on OSX).

**Update**

The xfbml works and correctly renders login buttons, displays basic user info.  And I can see the signed_request and access_token in the response headers from https://www.facebook.com/connect/ping?...  The sdk works but it won't give *me* the response.

Answer (score 0):

The least of a hack I could get working was putting everything behind an ssl proxy, even in development... which will make automated tests a headache.

I still don't know the cause, so I won't mark this as an answer.  This problem seems **very** localized.